# Mac OSX Bash script too many arguments during search

Tags: macos, bash

Using Mac OSX Bash script Error line 7: [: too many arguments
My script works just show the above error...

Any help would be great.

```
if [ ! -f B*.mp3 ]
then
echo "No files"
    exit 0  
    else 

do something....
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BASH you can do this to check for presence of matching file using `B*.mp3` pattern:

```
shopt -s nullglob
arr=(B*.mp3)

if (( ${#arr[@]} ))
then
   echo "No files"
   exit 0  
else 
   echo "do something...."
fi
```

Comment: I've tried all versions  and works great many thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

Bash will expand `B*.mp3` into a list of files; if there's more than one file it will be too many arguments for the `test` command (aka `[`.) You could instead use `find` to check for the presence of multiple files.

```
if [ -z "$(find . -name "B*.mp3" -maxdepth 1)" ]
then
echo "No files"
    exit 0  
    else 

do something....
fi
```

Comment: This will have the same problem unless you put double-quotes around the command substitution -- i.e. `"$(find ... )"`

Comment: Thanks, quotes in the right place are so easy to forget, and so important to remember...

Comment: I've tried all versions  and works great many thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

If there is no problem in using the list of positional parameters, this will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob     # Prevent that the B*.mp3 itself is the result.
set -- ./B*.mp3       # Find files that match the pattern.
if [ $# -lt 1 ];      # If there are 0 files ....
then
    echo "No files"
    exit 0  
else 
    do something....
fi
```

Comment: I've tried all versions  and works great many thanks for your help :D